# getting mask data into shader network through python or any other way

Tags: cycles-render-engine, blender-internal-render-engine, shaders, masking

is it possible to fetch bpy.data.mask[] into cycle or blender internal shader as texture? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a direct way to do this; Blender only has a [Mask node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/compositing/types/input/mask.html) in the render layer compositor, and not in the material compositor.